# Vertical alignment in color box

Tags: tcolorbox

In the following box I want to align "Example 1" with "Test" vertically. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tcbset{mystyle/.style={
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  outer arc=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  colframe=blue,
  colback=blue,
  attach boxed title to top left,
  boxed title style={
    colback=blue,
    outer arc=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    top=2pt,
    bottom=2pt
    }
  }
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{example}[1][]{
  mystyle,
  colback=white,
  rightrule=0pt,
  toprule=0pt,
  title={\bf Example \thetcbcounter},
  overlay unbroken and first={
      \path
        let
        \p1=(title.north east),
        \p2=(frame.north east)
        in
        node[anchor=west,color=blue,text width=\x2-\x1]
        at (title.east) {#1};
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
Test
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  What you mean with "align vertically". I guess that maybe you like that both text start at the same distance from the left border of `tcolorbox`? Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{mystyle/.style={
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt,
  colframe=blue, colback=white,
  left=4pt, right=4pt, top=2pt,
  attach boxed title to top left,
  boxed title style={colback=blue,
                     arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt,
                     left=4pt, right=4pt, top=2pt, bottom=2pt
                    } }
                        }% end of mystyle

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{example}[1][]%
{
    mystyle,
    title={\textbf{Example \thetcbcounter}},
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
Test
% \lipsum[1-5]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

or with longer text when the example box is split over two pages (in `example` box is considered text generated by `\lipsum[1-8]`)

[image]